# Removing hashes that have identical values for particular keys

Tags: ruby, hash, uniq

I have an `Array` of `Hash`es with the same keys, storing people's data.

I want to remove the hashes that have the same values for the keys `:name` and `:surname`. The rest of the values can differ, so calling `uniq!` on array won't work.

Is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a block to `uniq` or `uniq!`, the value returned by the block is used to compare two entries for equality:

```
irb> people = [{name: 'foo', surname: 'bar', age: 10}, 
               {name: 'foo', surname: 'bar' age: 11}]
irb> people.uniq { |p| [p[:name], p[:surname]] }
 => [{:name=>"foo", :surname=>"bar", :age=>10}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr=[{name: 'john', surname: 'smith', phone:123456789},
     {name: 'thomas', surname: 'hardy', phone: 671234992},
     {name: 'john', surname: 'smith', phone: 666777888}]
# [{:name=>"john", :surname=>"smith", :phone=>123456789},
#  {:name=>"thomas", :surname=>"hardy", :phone=>671234992},
#  {:name=>"john", :surname=>"smith", :phone=>666777888}]

 arr.uniq {|h| [h[:name], h[:surname]]}
# [{:name=>"john", :surname=>"smith", :phone=>123456789}, 
#  {:name=>"thomas", :surname=>"hardy", :phone=>671234992}]
```

Comment: I think that will only unique the surname. You want `+`, not `&&` inside the block. In fact, you probably want to construct an array for comparison.

Comment: carol adams and carola dams are not happy.

Comment: @steenslag hope they are happy now ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
unique_people = {}
person_array.each do |person|
  unique_people["#{person[:name]} #{person[:surname]}"] = person
end

array_of_unique_people = unique_people.values
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.delete_if do |h|
  a.select{|i| i[:name] == h[:name] and i[:surname] == h[:surname] }.count > 1
end
```